# The validate method resets the form field values in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a `User` bean that contains the user and the password and a validate method that verifies if the length of the user is greater than `0`. When I submit the form all values disappear from the form if there is an error. I don't find a way to solve this issue without `<s:textfield>.`

```java
public class UserController extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5538926739066161807L;

    private User userBean = new User();

    private UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();

    public User getUserBean() {
        return userBean;
    }

    public void setUserBean(User userBean) {
        this.userBean = userBean;
    }
    public void validate() {
            String user= userBean.getUsername();
            String password= userBean.getPassword();

            if ("".equals(user) || "".equals(password)) {
                addActionError(getText("userInvalid"));
        }
    }
}
```

JSP:

```jsp
<s:form action="createUser.action" method="POST">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="user">${action.getText('user')}</label> <input class="form-control" name="userBean.username" id="user"
        placeholder="Enter the user">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="user">${action.getText('password')}</label> <input class="form-control" name="userBean.password" id="password"
        placeholder="Enter the password">
</div>
<s:submit key="home.attractions.update" cssClass="btn btn-default" />
</s:form>
```

Comment: 1) Why *wouldn't* you use the S2 tags in the example, and 2) this is basic HTML-if you're unsure of HTML basics it might be worth taking a step back to learn the basics before perishing much further.

Comment: I think that it's not about the HTML, all works fine, but if there is any error, the validation from struts automatically resets the values.I think that I need something more specific for struts validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `property` tag to output a value to the input field

```jsp
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="userBean.username" id="user"
    placeholder="Enter the user" value="<s:property value='%{userBean.username}'/>">
```

Comment: Nothing is actually there after validation, even the userBean is null after that.

Comment: Is it the actual question?

Comment: Yes. I don't find any solution, so the only way is to use S2 tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any solution, so the only way is to use S2 tags :

```
   <s:textfield name="userBean.userName" key="register.username" 
cssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter the user" />

    <s:password name="userBean.password" key="register.password" 
cssClass="form-control margin10Top" placeholder="Enter the password" />
```

Comment: This is incorrect. If the S2 tags do it then your code can too; you're just not initializing the bean on a validation error. Taking a step back to learn the basics of the S2 request and validation flow would also be a good idea. While I don't see any reason to not use the S2 tags for this usecase, it also doesn't make sense to not understand why your original solution wasn't working. Check out the `Prepareable` interface and the associated `prepare` method.